# HTML Div convert into image with background image Html2canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am put canvas into one HTML div, After that i am converting this div into image using Html2canvas. HTML div successfully converted, but background image is not come.

I have seen one link but i am not sure. Because i have not seen any background image.
[Javascript html2canvas cant get background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461108/javascript-html2canvas-cant-get-background)

please suggest me any idea.

```js
$(function() { 
    $("#btnSave").click(function() { 
        html2canvas($("#html-to-canvas"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);          
                Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
                $("#canvas-image").append(canvas);              
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
 .bg-img
   {
     background-image:url('https://d2z4fd79oscvvx.cloudfront.net/0016463_petal_diamond_ring_320.jpeg');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
      
   }
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/gh-pages/build/html2canvas.js"></script>
  
<script src="https://raw.github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/v0.34/src/plugins/jquery.plugin.html2canvas.js"></script>
  <div style="width:450px;height:500px;border:1px solid #333" class=" html-to-canvas bg-img"   id="html-to-canvas">   
            <canvas id="canvas" style="margin-left:100px;margin-top:150px" width="200" height="300"></canvas>
   </div>
<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save PNG"/>
<div id="canvas-image"></div>
```

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: @Rayon Dabre. Background image is not come after click on save Png button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`html2canvas` or `Canvas2Image` does not work with external images.

> All the images that the script uses need to reside under the same origin for it to be able to read them.[Ref](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html#limitations)

Use relative path for the images and Try:

**Working code:**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btnSave").click(function() {
    html2canvas($("#html-to-canvas"), {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
        $("#canvas-image").append(canvas);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.bg-img {
  background-image: url('images/0016463_petal_diamond_ring_320.jpeg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 450px; height: 500px; border: 1px solid #333" class=" html-to-canvas bg-img" id="html-to-canvas">
  <canvas id="canvas" style="margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 150px" width="200" height="300"></canvas>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save PNG" />
<div id="canvas-image"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But why not taking server uploaded image.